# Custom php.ini is not taking effect

Tags: php, apache

The `php.ini` file used to take effect before July 23rd (2015) (new build date of PHP version), but after that build date, the `php.ini` file no longer takes effect.

I had tried renaming php.ini to `.user.ini`, but no change. I also had a chat with the [GoDaddy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoDaddy) server support team, but they don't know much about this.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use phpinfo(); to find out the path to the php.ini used. Maybe something changed in the settings.

Comment: @ Typoheads , I have checked all these already also contacted them again just now. So they made some changes again and the build date changes to previous state but its not working. I have tried re-uploading all files still it shows error. :(

Comment: Thanks all, OMG its starts working fine now. I think the changes might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It has started working fine now. I think [the changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31652375/custom-php-ini-not-taking-effect#comment51250877_31652375) in the settings might be the reason.